# MVC3 Razor and simulating same-page sections

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

Razor doesn't support same-page sections, so I can't do something like this:

```
@if (wrapSection)
{
    <div class="section-wrapped-in-div">
        @RenderSection("mySection")
    </div>
}
else
{
    @RenderSection("mySection")
}

@section mySection
{
    some stuff here...
}
```

I know I can accomplish this with a partial view, but this is specific to this page, and really would be best kept on the same page.

Is something like this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should make a [helper method](http://blog.slaks.net/2011/02/dissecting-razor-part-7-helpers.html):

```
@helper MySection(...) {
    ...
}

@MySection(...)
```

Unlike sections, helpers can also take parameters.

Comment: I knew it was probably something easy like that.  Thanks!